# Canvas, Path orientation change

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view

I use this sample code to capture credit card signature - http://corner.squareup.com/2010/07/smooth-signatures.html. I don't know how to scale path/canvas on orientation change. I use View's onSizeChange callback :

```
  @Override
  protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
      //View given size
      super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

      Log.d("Signature Old Height", String.valueOf(oldh));
      Log.d("Signature Height", String.valueOf(h));
      Log.d("Signature Old Width", String.valueOf(oldw));
      Log.d("Signature Width", String.valueOf(w));

      if(mCanvas != null){
          Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix(); 

          scaleMatrix.setScale((float)oldw/(float)w, (float)oldh/(float)h);
          path.transform(scaleMatrix);
          mCanvas.drawPath(path, paint);
      }
  }
```

But I doesn't work properly.

Comment: since you are calling mCanvas.drawPath(path, paint); outside onDraw method

Comment: So I should call invalidate method on signature view object in config change callback in fragment or activity ?

Comment: onSizeChanged is called by the system and then onDraw is called so you dont even have to call invalidate()